# Phase portrait Hamiltonian system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, stability, complex-systems

I have the Hamiltonian:

$$H(x,p)=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{x^4}{4}$$

When I find the critical points associatted with the system $\dot{x}=\frac{p}{m}$ and $\dot{p}=-kx^3$, I find only one critical point in (x=0,p=0). Then I get the Jacobian matrix, evaluate it at this point and I get its eigenvalues, $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$.

I know that when both eigenvalues are 0, the system is unstable, but after integrating it with matlab I find ellipses around (0,0) nonetheless.
What is happening?

I'm just learning dynamical systems, so a bit of help might come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously there is no harmonic approximation to your system near $(0,0)$ since your potential does not have a harmonic approximation near that point.  Nevertheless, the system is stable in the sense that, if you start near $(0,0)$, you will remain near $(0,0)$.  Moreover, the solution is still a bounded oscillation near the fixed point, but its not a harmonic oscillation.

Your system is called "intrinsically non-linear" and is discussed in P.Mohazzabi, "Theory and examples of intrinsically nonlinear oscillators", Am.J.Phys. vol. 72 (2004) 492-498.

The potential is illustrated in the figure.  The "issue" is that it is too flat to be approximated by something like $V\approx V_0+\epsilon\frac{\beta}{2}x^2$, i.e. $\beta=0$ for this potential: the usual stability theory, which is based on expansion of $H$ to $\epsilon^2$ near the fixed point, will just not work.

[image]

Comment: But why does starting near $(0,0)$  means remaining close to it?  Isn't the system unstable?

Comment: The system is stable as your phase curves are closed.  The potential has a minimum at $x=0$ but no osculating parabola: the motion is still bounded between two turning points; it's  just not harmonic motion to any approximation..

Comment: But what do the eigenvalues tell me about the stability then?

Comment: The eigenvalues tell you nothing because your system does not have a quadratic approximation.   Your Jacobian matrix contains 2nd derivatives, but all of those are $0$ at the fixed point so you get nothing out of that.

Comment: @mobzopi what your instructor or textbook has done is given you an example where there the standard expansion does not work.  The problem here is conceptual: simply because a system does not have a harmonic approximation does not mean the motion is unstable.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot Zero. Your answer is very useful!